# Emacs on Windows with a GameCube controller for note taking

Tags: microsoft-windows

I'm running out of desk space and can't fit both my textbook and my keyboard on my desk when I need to take notes. It doesn't hurt my wrists to keep a controller in my lap and I have a fair amount of GameCube controllers.

I know about Versor and joystick.el, but I don't think they support Windows, I'm not sure if they support behavior based on the joystick being analog, and they're definitely not meant for note taking.

Is there an existing way to nicely control Emacs with a GameCube controller, especially in a way that lets me customize it for note taking with Org?

If not, where should I start? What kind of examples of powerful editing with a controller can I look to so it doesn't just end up like an on-screen keyboard?

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll find anything more specific than Versor or joystick.el.  However, they may be helpful depending on your aims.  How do you envision using the controller for note taking if not to select from an on-screen keyboard?

Comment: I made a kind of "test model" with JoyToKey where pressing X once would allow me to select from AOEU, pressing it again would allow me to select from IDHT, etc., but that's really slow and I feel like it could be done much better/be much more powerful.

Comment: Specifically, I envision something like selecting a character from a wheel after pressing some sort of button, maybe cycling through by using the analog triggers? Or using the C Stick to select a starting letter and then the triggers to narrow down.